# Difference between GlassFish Server Open Source Edition and Java EE 6 SDK Update 2?

Tags: sdk, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

Can anyone tell me the difference between GlassFish Server Open Source Edition and Java EE 6 SDK Update 2?
As far as I know the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 is included in the Java EE 6 SDK Update 2. But what else? Couldnt find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [Java EE 6 SDK Downloads pag](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)e, I found the following:

Java EE 6 SDK Update 2 includes:

- GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1
- Java EE 6 Code Samples
- Java EE 6 API Documentation
- Java EE 6 Tutorial
- Your First Cup: An Introduction to
  the Java EE Platform